# How to copy the latest file modified with in a given date using unix shell commands?

Tags: shell, unix

I have to write a shell script that should copy the latest file in to a target directory. I use following shell command.

```
find . -type f -daystart -mtime -$dateoffset
```

It gives me the latest file set. But i need to get the latest file from that list and copy it to a target directory.

Thanks.

Comment: As far as I'm aware, the `-daystart` option is exclusive to GNU find, and is not found in other operating systems (FreeBSD, OSX, Solaris, etc).  Also, I think you can't do this safely in shell alone.  You might want to tag your question "linux" if you're set on using `-daystart`.

Answer (score 3):

I can't think of a way to do this in Bourne shell, since you need to use a tool that actually reads datestamps and sorts them, and Bourne shell doesn't do that.

But here's a solution in PHP:

```
<?php
$fdate=array();
foreach(glob("*") as $filename)
  $fdate[filemtime($filename)]=$filename;
krsort($fdate);
print "Newest item: " . reset($fdate) . "\n";'
?>
```

And if you hapen to be using **bash** instead of Bourne, he's a round-about way of getting what you want using an associative array:

```
#!/usr/local/bin/bash

declare -A fdate

highest=0
for file in *; do
  timestamp=$(stat -f '%m' "$file")
  fdate[$timestamp]="$file"
  if [ "$timestamp" -gt "$highest" ]; then
    highest=$timestamp
  fi
done

printf "Newest file: %s\n" "${fdate[$highest]}"
```

Note that I'm using FreeBSD, so this solution will also work in OSX, but if you happen to be using Linux, you'll need to figure out how your implementation of the `stat` command differs from mine.  (Hint: you may be able to use `stat -c '%y'`, but `man stat` to be sure.  Solaris, HP/UX, OSF/1, etc do not seem to include a `stat` binary that can be called from your shell.)

Answer (score 2):

*Update:*  @ghoti's neat solution is recommended over this one.  The following has been proved nonrobust.  It is left here only because, as a partial answer, it might point the way toward a better one-line solution.

```
ls -1dt $(find . -type f -daystart -mtime -$dateoffset) | head -n1
```

To copy the file to $TARGET_DIR,

```
A=$(ls -1dt $(find . -type f -daystart -mtime -$dateoffset) | head -n1)
if [ -n "$A" ] cp -u "$A" "$TARGET_DIR/$(basename $A)"
```

Comment: Rumour has it that [you shouldn't parse the output of `ls`](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs).

Comment: @thb I tried it. But seems it is not working. I tried to echo the variable A and nothing is displayed.

Comment: @ghoti:  I agree.  Another Unix tool that sorts filenames by modification time without much fuss however did not occur to me.  You?  But you are right.  If there is a chance that the filenames will be broken, my solution should not be used.

Comment: @EshanSudharaka:  Check that your `find` command is actually finding at least one file.  (When I try this, my `$A` is not empty.)

Comment: My approach is evidently broken.  I'll leave the answer posted because it may point the way toward a solution, but it is nonrobust.

Comment: I always copying a tar.gz file. so will that be a issue for my case ?

Comment: @EshanSudharaka, it depends on the name of your .tar.gz.  Your question didn't mention any constraints on the format of the filename, so the answers you're getting reflect general best practice rather than your specific use case.

Answer (score 1):

```
find . -name "*" -type f -daystart -mtime -$dateoffset | xargs -i mv {} /where/to/put/files
```

or

```
mv `find . -name "*" -type f -daystart -mtime -$dateoffset` /where/to/put/files
```

Comment: I think these both suffer from the same issues of parsing the output of `ls`.  What happens when there's a space in your filename, or a newline?

Answer (score 0):

If you use ls command with -lt option then it will give you newest file at top.
So using this you can easily extract latest file name

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like this:

```
find . -type f -name "*" -mtime +x_NUMBER_OF_DAYS|ls -lrt|awk -F' ' '{print $(COLUMN_NUMBER_IN_WHICH_FILE_NAME_APPEARS)}'|tail -1
```

This will give you the latest file till a given date.

As somebody suggested above daystart is only present in GNU flavor of find while -mtime is a more generic command.

P.S.: This again suffers from parsing problem if file name has space in it.But till we come-up with something more creative you can use this!